# View from a Join of two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

[Tables to Join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QsgA.jpg)

I attached an image explaining issues that I currently face at the moment. I was looking for a way to join two tables. Where first table has a relationship to the previous table that its foreign key in first table. The second table also have foreign key of the first table.

What I want is to output the information is a list of the records of the second table that has the foreign key of the first table as well as the foreign key of the previous table that only linked to first table only.

Thank you very much for your support and I am looking forward to hear from you all soon

Comment: Just want to clarify my request: Previous table refer to Table A, First Table is refer to Table B and Second table is refer to Table C

Comment: Add your sample output please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, try creating a view function. You can easily add tables and view the sql results after you connect all of them. It also has a built in function that will automatically creates the sql queries corresponding to your created view function.

Answer (score 0):

May you give this a try?

```
select a.clm,b.clm,c.clm from tableA as a 
inner join table b as b on a.clm = b.clm
inner join table c as c on c.clm = b.clm
```

where clm is the column that could be joined from table A as well as table B as well as table c

If ever, kindly give us a bit more info about

Comment: Halo Mr. J..I have more info on this issue on my answer below

Comment: Yep! I think I might be able to help you, but I would like to request your column names, well, not exactly them. and the names of the columns that could be joined.